# Why I got this error while working with tfestimators package in R?

Tags: r, tensorflow

I am trying to use `tfestimator` package in R to replicate an example using the `mtcars` data frame to make predictions with a linear model but I get this errors:

```
# input function
  input <- input_fn(mtcars, 
              features = c("drat", "mpg", "am"),
              response = "vs",
              batch_size = 128,
              epochs = 3)
# feature columns
cols <- feature_columns(
  column_numeric("drat"),
  column_indicator("am")
)

Error in py_get_attr_impl(x, name, silent) : 
  AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.feature_column.feature_column' has no attribute 'numeric_column'
In addition: Warning message:
`quo_expr()` is deprecated as of rlang 0.2.0.
Please use `quo_squash()` instead.
This warning is displayed once per session. 


# construct feature columns
linear_feature_columns <- feature_columns(column_numeric("mpg"))
dnn_feature_columns <- feature_columns(column_numeric("drat"))

Error in py_get_attr_impl(x, name, silent) : 
  AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.feature_column.feature_column' has no attribute 'numeric_column'
```

I am working with the latest version of TensorFlow and I don't know why I am getting this error.

Comment: It might help if you provide the code that causes this error.